# What happens with the current in a circuit that is not consumed by any device?

Tags: current, current-measurement

I am a total newbie at electrical stuff. I have been reading a while about voltage, current and resistance. I have many doubts but I will try to summarize them:

1. What happens with the current in a circuit that is not consumed by any device? I explain myself: imagine I have an electric circuit with one battery of 1,5V. I put a small light bulb of 1,5V too in the circuit that needs 0,01A to work. Lets assume the current is 0,03A in the circuit(calculated from the Ohm Law). In order the light bulb not to burn with 0,03A, how does it to prevent from burning with these 0,03A when it only needs 0,01A?

Thanks a lot

Comment: First you say the bulb needs .01 A, then you say "the circuit" draws 0.03 A. But "the circuit" is just the lamp. If the lamp draws 0.01 A, it draws 0.01 A. If it draws 0.03 A, it draws 0.03 A. It can't be both at the same time. If there are more devices in "the circuit" than just the battery and the lamp, then you need to draw a schematic to clarify.

Comment: Your circuit setup is not clear. Add a schematic.

Comment: What happens with the flowing water in your pipe that is not consumed?

Comment: `needs 0,01 amps to work` means, at least 0,01A has to pass through the light bulb for it to light up ..... it is not the same as `draws 0,01A` ..... your example light bulb has a resistance of 150 ohms, so it will draw 0,01A when connected to 1,5V battery .... it will draw much more when connected to 3,0V battery, and it will probably burn up

Comment: I thought the wrong way, I see it now. I cannot calculate the current in a circuit without considering the resistance of the bulb itself, right? If I have a circuit with a battery of 12 Voltios and I want to use a lumb of 1.5V 0.3A, the resistance of the circuit would be = 12/5(internal resistance of the bulb), right?

Comment: No. The resistance, R, of the lamp will be 1.5/0.3 the current through it will be 12/R

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What happens with the current in a circuit that is not consumed by any device?

If it is not consumed then it doesn't flow in the first place.

> Imagine I have an electronic circuit with one battery of 1,5 volts. I put a small light bulb of 1,5 volts too in the circuit that needs 0,01 amps to work.

Assuming the bulb is rated for 1.5 V then from Ohm's law we know that the resistance is given by \$ R = \frac {V}{I} = \frac {1.5}{0.01} = 150 \ \Omega \$.

> Lets assume the current is 0,03 amps in the circuit (calculated from the Ohm Law).

But it can't pass 0.03 A. It's resistance is too high. Effectively it *resists* the flow of current and limits it to 0.01 A.

> In order the light bulb not to burn with 0,03 amps, how does it to prevent from burning with these 0,03 amps when it only needs 0,01 amps?

Resistance!

My house is connected to the Irish national grid which has a peak generation capacity of 5 GW. What limits the current drawn by my 20 W LED lamp on my desk and prevents all 5 GW exploding beside my head? Answer: its resistance to current flow.

Comment: I don't know how many times I've seen your Irish national grid analogy, but I'll still upvote every time I see it.. lol

Comment: Thanks. Am I getting repetitive? I try to vary it a bit. This time I considered it all being consumed beside my head. Ideas for next time? Maybe a *Back to the Future* guitar amplifier.

Comment: Maybe use some random chinese guy as an example, he has a lightbulb connected to the 22GW Three Gorges dam :D

Answer (score 1):

Your bulb has a power limit and a resistance.

Let's imagine that the nominal power is 15mW and its resistance is 150 ohms.

[In actual bulbs, the resistance is dependant on temperature, it is not a constant]

Most of it goes into heat, a LED gives more light and less heat than a incandescent bulb.

Now you need to consider these equations :

- V = R . I
- P = V . I = V² / R = R . I²

You can use a constant voltage generator, or a constant current generator.

Constant voltage is far more common, for example a 1.5V battery.
Connected to that battery, your lamp will dissipate 15mW : P=1.5² * 150 = 0.015. Great.

If you connect it to a 12V supply, the power will reach 1Watt, which may be far above its rated power. If you add a series resistance, the current and voltage across the lamp will be lower, but the energy dissipated in the resistance is wasted.

You could also use a 0.01mA current source and the lamp will also dissipate 15mW  : 150 * 0.01²

[LED lamps are often powered with constant current, because of variations of resistance between chips and because of negative temperature coefficients]

Answer (score 1):

A circuit can't draw 2 different value of current at the same time. If it draws 0.01A, There is no meaning in saying it draws 0.03A.
If you provide a schematic we(the community) can help. Because your question is not clear.

NB: You will come across superposition theorem, where you add current drawn from different sources at the same time to find actual value. But that's a different concept.

Answer (score 1):

It helps to visualize electricity as water flowing through pipes.

Voltage = Water Pressure

Current = Water Flow

Resistance = Flow restriction (like a narrow section of pipe)

Your battery puts out a "pressure" of 1.5v

Your lamp is similar to a resistor. When the spec sheet says 1.5v, 0.01A that actually means, "when the pressure is 1.5, the flow will be 0.01 and the lamp will operate".

So your question about "what if the flow is 0.03, and the lamp only needs 0.01" is nonsensical. The lamp itself will limit the flow to 0.01 at a pressure of 1.5. So if the flow is higher than that, it must be going around the lamp somehow.

Answer (score 0):

But current is not consumed!  ENERGY is consumed, and energy-flow is measured in watts.  The amps is a closed loop, a 'complete circuit.'  I think you have an incorrect picture of electricity.

Briefly:   the path of current is a complete circle.   Like a flywheel, or a drive-belt.  The word "current" means "rate of charge-flow," and charges are the things that are flowing.   The charges fill the entire circuit all the time (because metals are made of movable electrons.)   Electric circuits are like flywheels, like drive-belts, where the electrons are like the substance of the moving flywheel.

Imagine that a circuit is like the tire of an upside-down bicycle.  The rubber is the electrons, and the rotation of the wheel is the current; the amperes.   Rubber is not consumed.  The path for rubber is a complete circuit.   In circuits, the charges flow in a closed loop.   There is no source, there is no "consumer," and no charges are being gained or lost as the circuit operates.  The only source of charges is the copper itself, since copper contributes the ocean of movable electrons.   (Note that the path of current is *through* any power supply, through the battery and back out again.)   A battery is a charge-pump, not a charge source.   When we "charge" a battery, we don't put any electrons into it.   We're charging it with a "charge" of energy, not of charge.

OK, now suppose we have our bicycle wheel, and we spin it with one hand while letting our other hand rub against it.   The first hand injects energy into the entire wheel instantly, increasing the speed.  The friction hand takes energy back out again, slowing the wheel again.  You've asked: "What happens to the rubber that is not consumed by any load?"   No rubber is ever consumed.  The number of amperes flowing into a motor are exactly the same as the amperes flowing out through the other wire.   Yes, the motor is doing work and consuming energy, but electricity is not energy, electricity like a drive-belt, and it flows through, and back out again.

In other words, amperes are not watts.   Amperes are the flow rate of electricity, with a closed circular path (and no electricity is gained or lost.)   Watts on the other hand are the flow rate of energy, and a battery puts energy into the entire circuit, while a motor takes it back out again at the same time.

Well, what happens to any energy which isn't consumed by the electric motor?

Look again at our bicycle wheel analogy.   If the friction-hand doesn't consume the energy being added by the pushing-hand, that means the friction-hand has grabbed the wheel, and the wheel stops (the current is zero.)   The pushing-hand still pushes, but the wheel doesn't move.   The friction hand has "told the power supply" to stop delivering energy!

That's what happens when you unplug a lamp in your house: you've instantly "told" the distant giant dynamo to stop moving the circle of charges in the loop which includes your lamp.  The push, the voltage is still there.  But the brakes are engaged, and the wheel cannot move.

When people say that electricity is like water, they really mean that electricity is like a system of water-filled hoses with no bubbles anywhere.  The water moves slowly in circles, like drive-belts, while the mechanical energy flies across the system, going from the pump to your personal turbine-motor.

Don't be put off by this, because most people make this same mistake:  we all think that water is a form of energy ("electricity is a form of energy.")   We think that only one thing flows inside of circuits, when actually the electricity flows slowly like a circular drive-belt, while the energy flows almost instantly.  Two things flow in circuits, not just "electricity."  Their flows are measured in amperes of electricity-flow, and watts of energy-flow.

And in a power cord, the energy flows in the same direction in both wires!   (But then in the bicycle wheel, the invisible energy flowed instantly across both halves of the wheel, while the rubber itself moved slowly in a circle.)